# How to add treeview selected items inside the datagridview columns as a treeview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, treeview

I have a form which is having one treeview and datagridview in a form, now i want to insert treeview selected nodes to inside the datagridview with a treeview!

treeview(treeview selected nodes) inside datagridview!

Comment: You need to show us some code so that we can help you modify it to achieve your goal. We don't write your code from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this which has `Treeview` with `Columns` 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns

Comment: How to Create TreeView inside GridView?

Comment: whether you need to create Treeview inside GridViewRows ? Well if so what is the use of it ?

Comment: I have attached screenshot, the files are exported from treeview to datagridveiw, see there is treeview inside datagridview (PST Path..)

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31276/Add-Group-Collapse-Behavior-on-a-Listview-Control)   you can modify this as you required.

Comment: Do you exactly know the question?